# Rogue using Dual Wield and Sneak Attack

Tags: dnd-5e, rogue, sneak-attack

I have heard that when a rogue dual wields, the rogue has one primary action which is used to attack main hand and a bonus action which is used to attack off hand.

My question is: can the rogue attack with the main hand action and with off hand bonus action and still use the rogue's sneak attack ability?

Answer (score 21):

**Yes or No, depending on how you meant the question.**

Sneak attack is a once per turn feature, so you may not use it on both attacks. However, since sneak attack affects one creature you hit with an attack if you have advantage on the attack roll, while using a finesse or a ranged weapon, dual wielding is a decent option, as you have two chances to hit and apply that extra sneak attack damage.

*Note: You don’t need advantage on the attack roll if another enemy of the target is within 5 feet of it, that enemy isn’t incapacitated, and you don’t have disadvantage on the attack roll.*

Answer (score 5):

As stated by The Amused Muse, Sneak Attack is a once per turn feature and will naturally only apply itself on **one** of your hits (whether it is because you have an Advantage on the attack roll or an enemy of your target is within 5ft of them). An attack of opportunity can also trigger it as a reaction, if I'm not mistaken. While we're on that, I might also mention that a Sneak Attack will also benefit from a Critical Hit, meaning you'll be getting twice the dice/twice the damage.

Attacking with a second weapon is considered a bonus action. As long as you're wielding **light weapons** you can attempt to make a hit with the second one. That being said, if it connects it will not benefit from your modifier. You need to bear in mind you won't be able to use things like **Cunning Action** if you use a 2nd attack.

Comment: Attacking with a second weapon is **not** part of your normal attack action, it's a separate *bonus* action (under *Two-Weapon Fighting* in the PHB pg.195). This is an important distinction to make because it means you can't also use your bonus action that turn for things like *Cunning Action* or casting certain spells if you take the *Arcane Trickster* archtype. Whereas as you've written it, it sounds like you *could* still use a bonus action.

Comment: Since you bring up the attack of opportunity, you should clarify that you could use sneak attack with it in addition to when you used it on one of your regular attacks, so long as if was on someone else's turn. I.e. You can use SA twice in one round, so long as it's only once a turn.